# Help to understand Noether Normalization Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I'm trying to understand the statement of the Noether Normalization Theorem:

[image]

How can $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ be equal to $k[x]$? a typical element of $k[x]$ is for example $ax^2+bx$ with $a,b\in k$, while an element of $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is for example $cx_1^3x_2x_3^2+x_1^2+d$ with $c,d\in k$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's just Lang setting up notation. $k[x]$ will be a convenient abbreviation for $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$. Some people will write $k[\underline{x}]$.

Comment: @Hoot: It seems we gave the same answer simultaneously. Normally I would agree a comment is enough, but I feared this question would remain forever unanswered...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here $x$ is just a (relatively common) shorthand for the entire list of variables $x_1, \ldots, x_n$. Typically this is denoted $x_1, \ldots, x_n = \underline{x}$, but for whatever reason the author chose not to denote it this way.

Comment: ok, so the same for $k[y]=k[y_1,\ldots y_r]$